# Getting an array of a property from an object array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I need to extract an array of a single property from a custom object array. eg.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject 
{
    int sampleNumber;
    NSString *sampleName;
}
```

I have an array of `MyClass` instances called `myArray`. I want to then get an array of the `sampleName` strings. Is there a way to do it without stepping through the whole array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray;

for (MyClass *thisInstance in myArray) 
{    
    [stringArray addObject:thisInstance.sampleName];
}
```

I attempted to search for a similar question in Objective-C but found it only in the PHP and LINQ sections.

Comment: I’ve fixed one typo in the declaration of `MyClass`: you need to declare `sampleName` as `NSString *` instead of `NSString`. I’ve also replaced `foreach` with `for`.

Comment: Thanks, I came back to edit it and found you had already answered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html):

```
NSArray *stringArray = [myArray valueForKey:@"sampleName"];
```

Comment: thanks so much @Bavarious, especially for the quick response. It took me longer to test it out than for you to answer it. I love this forum!